# C# Get printer preferences remaining pages

Tags: c#, printing, dialog, preferences

I need to get the remaining pages to a special print dialog:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/837/imagegu.png/

I can launch this dialog with the next lines:

```
private void OpenPrinterPropertiesDialog()
{
    PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
    IntPtr hDevMode = printerSettings.GetHdevmode(printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings);
    IntPtr pDevMode = GlobalLock(hDevMode);
    int sizeNeeded = DocumentProperties(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, printerSettings.PrinterName,     IntPtr.Zero, pDevMode, 0);
    IntPtr devModeData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeNeeded);

    DocumentProperties(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, printerSettings.PrinterName, devModeData, pDevMode, 14);
    // <--- Here the print dialog appears

    GlobalUnlock(hDevMode);
    printerSettings.SetHdevmode(devModeData);
    printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.SetHdevmode(devModeData);
    GlobalFree(hDevMode);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(devModeData);
}
```

I was searching in the msdn documentation in PrintDocument, PrinterSettings, etc and didnt find any way to get this information values, How can I get the remaining pages values of this preferences dialog without open it? is it possible? I need to know the remaining pages of the printer.
Thanks.

Edited: I need to get the information values in the box Remain in the capture picture, the blank pages of the printer.

Comment: Reading this question and image, I'm not sure whether you want to get "the number of pages in the print queue" or "the number of pieces of blank paper in the paper bin"

Comment: The number of pieces of blank paper, in the image I uploaded to imageshak: In the box Remain, when the printer is not sleeping they it sends the remaining blank pages inside the printer, so I would control how many copies can I do in my application before of printing.

Comment: Most printers I know only are capable of detecting either "there is paper in the paper bin" or "the paper bin is empty".  Does your printer have a "pages left" measurement ability?  You may have to write your code custom for each printer that supports it.

Comment: How can you see, in this dialog box appears and the printer have this ability of control the pages left, but I dont know how can I access to this values in C#. I got to launc this dialog box to show the information, I would recognize characters of this image to get the values, but the perfect solution it would be to get the values programmatically with any way. I suppose that each printer have own preferences, it must be possible to get that information, but how?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific in .NET to get *that* data.  Possibly, you could get it through DEVMODE.dwDriverExtra (via PInvoke), but you'd have to know the structure of the data (i.e. you'd have to contact Mistubishi) and where in that data the page remaining count is stored--if at all.  There's nothing that says everything that is visible in the properties dialog is accessible programmatically.

Comment: Clearly you'd have to research the printer's specific technical details.  The dwDriverExtra data is probably the right way to go about it.

Comment: Any help for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197606/setting-printer-preference-page-orientation-to-landscape/13199652#13199652 ?