# Setting Printer Preference - Page Orientation to Landscape

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, landscape-portrait

I would like to set the Page orientation to LandScape for printing excel worksheet from my excel Vsto project. Manually page orientation is set from the **Printer Preference** window which is popped up from 'Print' form.

I need some automation which will set the orientation to LandScape every time user gives print command.

[image]

I have noticed that if i set the orientation to **LandScape** from my excel application, it stays same for if i want to give a print from a MS-word application & vice versa. So there has to be some kind of flag which can be changed from any simple winform application.

Is there any way i could manipulate the properties ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find any way we could customize the printer settings of any individual printer. Here's the code which worked for me for EXCEL application.

`CommonData._WORKBOO`K is a static workbook object

```
Worksheet ws = CommonData._WORKBOOK.Application.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;

var _with1 = ws.PageSetup;

_with1.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
CommonData._WORKBOOK.Application.Dialogs[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogPrint].Show(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following below should work for you

```
public void CustPrinting() 
{
   try 
     {
       strPrint = new StreamReader (filePath);
     try 
       {
         printFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
         PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument(); 
         pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
         pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;
         // Set the page orientation to landscape.
         pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
         pd.Print();
       } 
     finally 
     {
       strPrint.Close() ;
     }
   } 
   catch(Exception ex)
   { 
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
 }
```